# Replicating Camera View - DeviceOrientationControls to TrackballControls

Tags: camera, three.js, rotation, quaternions

I am trying to replicate a view from a phone (using DeviceOrientationControls) to a desktop (using TrackballControls). I am passing the view state (camera position & direction) through an intermediary server, and have that part mostly working.

I'm having trouble setting the camera rotation on the desktop. The cameras are sync'd to look at the same point, but the view on the desktop (receiving the view state from the phone) rotates around the view angle.

I definitely don't fully understand quaternions or rotation order. I've tried applying those, but clearly I'm out of my element. I guess I'm just looking for some hints on how to sync the camera rotation on the desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I had a (trackball) controls.update() in my animate() that was blowing away the rotation that I was setting. Camera position and direction are not changed by this, but the rotation (or the "roll" of the camera) was.

In TrackballControls, it would be nice to have a setting for programmatically updating the camera's rotation that wouldn't get squashed by a call to rotateCamera(). I'll have to think about that, because it doesnt seem like it would be easy to implement.